Problem with memcpy implementation in x86_64 assembly language
I have a task to implement memcpy function in x86_64 assembler with this signature:
extern void* my_memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, uint32_t count);

I wrote it:

.intel_syntax noprefix

.text
.global my_memcpy

my_memcpy:
    mov ecx, edx
    shr rcx, 3
    rep movsq

    mov ecx, edx
    and ecx, 7
    rep movsb

- mov rax, rdi

    ret

In my implementation there is a problem with the test when the value from src = “abcde” is copied to dest = “00000”. When comparing memcpy result and dest, it turns out that the result is “abcde” and dest is empty. And I seem to copy the result to rax before ret correctly. Moreover, if I don't write mov rax, rdi, this test will pass and everything will work correctly. Could you please tell me how it works here and what the problem is?

Have you set or cleared the direction flag? Related: What are CLD and STD for in x86 assembly language?

Apparently the default is DF = 0, because cld didn't change anything

You don't have CLD in the code. It remains set the way some previous code set it. The default state is after RESET.

I mean I added cld but the result is the same

If you using the returned rdi that won't be pointing to the beginning of the range.

@WeatherVane thanks a lot, I wrote "mov rax, rdi" at the beginning and now it works correctly

@WeatherVane: Both major x86-64 calling conventions (x86-64 SysV and Win x64) require/guarantee DF=0 before/after calls.  You don't need cld instructions unless you've set DF yourself.  But yeah, standard memcpy (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) returns dest so indeed mov rax, rdi needs to be at the beginning.

@mackenzie: on most modern x86-64 CPUs (Intel at least have the ERMSB feature, not sure about AMD), a single rep movsb would be more efficient than rep movsq plus a cleanup with rep movsb, especially for the common case of smallish copies that are a multiple of 8 bytes.  Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy .  Of course for small copies the microcode startup overhead is still a problem, which is why user-space libc implementations use XMM or YMM vector registers.  Kernel implementations typically avoid vector regs.
